# How to fix: Access Denied: Specified user is not a member of TelnetClients groups?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, telnet

I have two computers one running windows xp(professional) and other is windows 7(Home premium).I want to connect from xp to windows 7, but I am getting error like this

**Access Denied: Specified user is not a member of TelnetClients groups.The server administrator must add this user to above group.**

I searched in the net that I have to change the local security settings. I changed the
***Network access:Sharing and security model for local accounts*** value from **guest only** to **classic** in windows xp but I did not found this option in my windows 7 home premium. So what should I do? Is that not possible to connect to windows 7 home premium using telnet beacause remote desktop connection is also not possible in home premium.

Comment: Ensure telnet is enabled on both ends, check to see that the port(s) you are trying to connect to are open, ensure the user account has the correct permissions.

Comment: don't have win7 in fromt of me , but i checked google for that option in windows 7, and maybe home premium doesn't have it, as you suggest. but have you checked Computer Configuration --- Windows Settings --- Security Settings --- Local Policies --- Security Options, Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts

Comment: I am talking about win7 home premium. the option you are talking about may be avaiable on other versions.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using Telnet?  Why not RDP?

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to use the telnet server on Windows 7 (Home Premium). After you've installed the telnet server, and turned on the telnet service, you have to add users to the TelnetClients group. The problem is that the snapin to do this is disabled in Home Premium. But you can still do this from the command line:

1. Open a command prompt using "Run as administrator"
2. Enter the following command: `net localgroup TelnetClients /add [username]`
3. You should see:

   > The command completed successfully.
4. To verify, run this command: `net localgroup TelnetClients`
5. You should see the account listed as a Member of the TelnetClients group.

Answer (score 1):

On the windows 7 computer (aka Telnet-server) add the desired user to the TelnetClients group like so:

Right click 'Computer' > 'Manage' > 'System Tools' > 'Local Users and Groups' > 'Groups' > double click 'TelnetClients' > 'Add' and then add the user you want to have access.

Remember you have to login with a username/password from the Windows 7 computer, even when connecting from the xp computer.

Comment: As said in the comments of the original question, Home Premium does not have the Local Users and Groups menu.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to connect to windows 7 home premium using a telnet connection

please follow the steps below:

Telnet service in Windows enabled. From the Start -> Control Panel.

In the View by option, select Category.

Select the Programs icon.

Select Turn Windows features on or off.

[image]

Cek list Telnet Client.

[image]

Select OK, then the process for Telnet will feature in the switch, wait a moment.

To ascertain whether we have an active Telnet please check the Command Prompt (CMD) and type the command "Telnet". If there is a display as shown below means the Telnet Client Service already active. To exit type "quit"

[image]

On Windows XP by default in the Command Prompt command can be used Telnet. If our Windows XP computer remotely from another computer you can not access the full. So that other computers can access the full we have to enable the Telnet service in Windows XP.
The steps are as follows:

Click Start> Control Panel.

Select Administrative Tools.

[image]

Then select the icon Services

[image]

Select the Telnet service. By default Startup Type to Disable Telnet value. If the remote from another computer does not give full access. Here we change the value to Automatic.

[image]

Click 2 times Telnet, and then change the Startup Type to Automatic. Click the Apply button> Start> OK

Setting is finished, now time for us remotely Windows XP from Windows 7.

In Windows 7 (with IP address 192.168.1.10) open Command Prompt (CMD), then type the command "telnet"

Then the display will show the Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client.

On Windows XP that will diremote using telnet, IP is set Addressnya, namely:

192.168.1.11, which is already connected to Windows 7. To test the connection please open a Command Prompt (CMD) and then do a ping to the computer's IP to be in remote or vice versa. If no replay please correct.

In Windows 7, Type the command "open 192.168.1.11". then be asked "Do You want to send any way?", answer yes premises pressing the "Y" and then press Enter.

[image]

After that ask for user login in windows XP. Type the Administrator and the password.

[image]

Finally over. If successful will look like this:
[image]

Comment: u certainly didn't read my question carefully. I have done these steps.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm wrong answer