# How do I modify user groups in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts

I need to add myself to the TelnetClients group on Windows 8, I knew how to do this in Windows 7 and before that but I guess everything has changed. I have looked through all the account settings and came up with nothing.

Comment: The process should be exactly the same.  What version of Windows 8 exactlly `Professional` or `Core`?

Comment: I assume I have core then. I go to **Control Panel** -> **Administrative Tools** -> **Computer Management**. I can't find **Local Users and Groups** anywhere.

Comment: You need to verify what version of Windows 8 you have. Check the same way you would on Windows 7, hit properties on `My Computer, and post the results. If you do have `Windows 8 Core` then I don't think you can do what you want.

Comment: Can you manage other groups on Windows 8, but not TelnetClients?

Comment: It says my Windows Edition is just "Windows 8" so I assume its core since it doesn't say "Windows 8 Professional." It would be unfortunate if I couldn't do it though. Nope, I can't manage any groups since I can't figure out how to.

Comment: I have tried running **lusrmgr.msc** and it says "**This snapin may not be used with this edition of Windows 8. To manage user accounts for this computer, use the Accounts tool in the Control Panel.**." Unfortunately that doesn't let me modify groups. So I guess I can't modify groups but if there was a way around it, it would be nice to know.

Comment: @WalterM - There isn't away around it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the command 'net localgroup' as follows. This works on non-Pro Win 8 as well.

1. Open a privileged command prompt:
   Open Explorer and search for 'cmd.exe'. When it appears in the file list, right-click and select 'Run as Administrator'.
2. Run the command:
   In the privileged command prompt window, enter the command as follows:

   ```
   net localgroup [groupname] [username] /add
   ```

   To see a list of local groups available, just type:

   ```
   net localgroup
   ```

   To see other options, type:

   ```
   net help localgroup
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Type `lusrmgr.msc` in "RUN" dialogue box which is accessible  via shortcut key combination <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

I must mention I'm not sure if it works in non "Pro" versions of windows 8.
you can try it any way...

Comment: From [olsonm](http://superuser.com/users/220833/olsonm): In Windows 8 core using lusrmgr.msc will not work as it will tell you the snapin is unavailable with that version. I just tried it.

Comment: Works in Win 8 pro for sure. The `net localgroup` option is your best bet in Home (non pro)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and it certainly does get the job done with Pro.  However, is there not a way to Navigate to this screen?  Otherwise, I think it's a bit asinine of Microsoft to level this out!

Comment: I'm on "Windows 8,1 with Bing" (not sure why there's a specific windows edition for Bing!?) and this doesn't work there.  Reckon it definitely requires Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Per the additional detail in the comments, and the last post [on this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/1af67021-f23d-4fdb-b7b2-84b73437ec6b), Windows 8 non-Pro lacks the Local Users and Groups entry in Computer Management.  It is also lacking the Group Policy Editor.

If you need to manage groups on your computer, you need Windows 8 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

The method described for Win7, in the Link titled "Editing TelnetClients Group on Windows 7 Home Premium " ([How do you resolve the error "Access Denied: Specified user is not a member of TelnetClients groups."?](https://superuser.com/questions/439737/how-do-you-resolve-the-error-access-denied-specified-user-is-not-a-member-of-t/559708#559708)) also works for Win8 STD edition - I just verified it:

```
Open a command prompt using "Run as administrator"
Enter the following command: net localgroup TelnetClients /add [username]
You should see: "The command completed successfully."
To verify, run this command: net localgroup TelnetClients
You should see the account listed as a Member of the TelnetClients group
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Windows 8 to try this, but this works on Windows 7 Home Premium which also doesn't have the Group Policy Editor, so I'd guess something similar to this will work on Windows 8 too:

[Editing TelnetClients Group on Windows 7 Home Premium](https://superuser.com/questions/439737/how-do-you-resolve-the-error-access-denied-specified-user-is-not-a-member-of-t/559708#559708)
(See my post in this thread.)

If someone can confirm that or something similar to it works on Windows 8, please feel free to update this post with the proper Windows 8 speak.

Also, if you want to update another group, simply change TelnetClients to the desired group name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft Management Console (mmc.exe).

1. From the start screen search for (just start typing)  mmc.exe.
2. Click on mmc from list to start it.
3. You may be asked for permission.
4. Once the mmc starts choose file-> Add/Remove Snap-in.
5. Choose the Local Users and Groups Snap-in (Note all the other things you can add!).
6. Click add.
7. Click finish .
8. Click OK.
9. Navigate to the group you want. Double click the group, then you can add users.